# How to use lapply with a condition in R to fit only one element each time

Tags: r

Suppose I have two vectors. Suppose further that I would like my function takes only one values of each vector and return me the output. Then, I would like another function to check the values of each run. If the output of the previous run is smaller than the new one. Then, I would like my function to stop and return me all the previous values. My original function is very complicated (estimation models). Hence, I try to provide an example to explain my idea.

Suppose that I have these two vectors:

```
set.seed(123)
x <- rnorm(1:20)
y <- rnorm(1:20)
```

Then, I would like to write a function which only takes one values of each vector and multiplied them. Then, return me the output. Then, I would like the function to check if the previous multiplication is smaller than the new one or not. If yes, then stop and return me all the previous multiplication.

I tried this:**However, this functions takes all the values at once and return me a list of the multiplication. I was thinking about using lapply, to fit one element at a time but I do not know how to work with the conditions.**

```
myfun <- function(x, y, n){
    multi <- list()
    for ( i in 1:n){
        multi[[i]] <- x[[i]]*y[[i]]
    }
    return(multi)
}
myfun(x,y,10)
```

**Here is another try**

```
 x <- rnorm(1:20)
y <- rnorm(1:20)
myfun <- function(x, y){
            multi <- x*y

    return(multi)
}
```

This is the first function. I would like to run it element by element. Each time, I would like it to returns me only one multiplication result. Then, another function (wrapper function) check the result. It the second output of the first function (multiplication function) is larger than the first one, then stop, otherwise keep going.

Comment: Could you add `set.seed` so the randomness is pinned down and you can say exactly what behavior you expect for a given x and y?

Comment: @Frank Thank you so much for your comment. I would like to run the multiplication element by element. Then, if the previous multiplication is smaller than the new one, I would like the function to stop.

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarifying. If you want to compare the current value against all preceding values, you can check `z = x*y; z == cummax(z)` The condition is trivially true for the first value, so you can add `z == cummax(z) & seq_along(z) > 1L`. To find the first value where this condition holds (if any), there's `which(z == cummax(z) & seq_along(z) > 1L)[1L]`... not sure if this is the direction you're looking for. If you showed exactly the output desired for the example's x and y, I think it would help.

Comment: @Frank. thank you so much for your help. I would like the multiplication in a separate function. Then, I would like to check its output. So, I should have a warper function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to write a function which only takes one values of each vector and multiplied them. Then, return me the output. Then, I would like the function to check if the previous multiplication is smaller than the new one or not.
>
> I would like the multiplication in a separate function. Then, I would like to check its output. So, I should have a warper function.

You can apply a for loop with a stopping condition, similar to what you have already:

```
# example input
set.seed(123)
x <- rnorm(1:20)
y <- rnorm(1:20)

# example function
f = function(xi, yi) xi*yi

# wrapper
stopifnot(length(x) == length(y))
res = vector(length(x), mode="list")

for (i in seq_along(x)){
  res[[i]] = f(x[[i]], y[[i]])
  if (i > 1L && res[[i]] > res[[i-1L]]) break
}

res[seq_len(i)]
```

Comments:

- It is better to predefine the max length `res` might need (here, `length(x)`), rather than expanding it in the loop.
- For this function (multiplication), there is no good reason to proceed elementwise. R's multiplication function is vectorized and fast.
- You don't need to use a list-class output for this function, since it is returning doubles; `res = double(length(x))` should also work.
- You don't need to use list-style accessors for `x`, `y` and `res` unless lists are involved; `res[i] = f(x[i], y[i])` should work, etc.